# Where is the Artifactory config file located after installing with RPM?

Tags: artifactory

After installing Artifactory using the [RPM installer](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+on+Linux+Solaris+or+Mac+OS#InstallingonLinuxSolarisorMacOS-RPMorDebianInstallation), where is the Artifactory XML configuration file stored? (The one you can see through the UI at "Admin > Advanced > Config Descriptor")

Have been looking around in "/opt/jfrog/artifactory" and "/etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory" - but havent been able to locate this specific file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the RPM installer, but I've used the Debian installer and the Docker image, and I'd imagine they all put it in the same place:

```
/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/artifactory.config.latest.xml
```

It should also be accessible by symbolic link from:

```
/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/artifactory.config.latest.xml
```

Other files in that directory in the form of `artifactory.config.latest.[numbers].xml` are backups or older edits of this file.